# Sandcastle/SHFB. Add platform icons and version info to help file pages

Tags: documentation, documentation-generation, sandcastle, xml-comments, shfb

I am building help file for my library using Sandcastle Help File Builder. The library has three versions (.NET, Silverlight and Windows Phone 7) built from the same code base.

I would like to add platform icons next to method names and version information at the bottom of the help file pages. Something like on screenshots below. How can I add such information to my help file?

[image: Platform icons next to method names]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This question was answered in the Sandcastle discussions forums [here](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/discussions/279248).

Paul Selormey wrote a very detailed 3-part blog that discusses how to do this:
[Part 1](http://sandcastleassist.blogspot.com/2012/01/sandcastle-version-information-part-13.html)
[Part 2](http://sandcastleassist.blogspot.com/2012/02/sandcastle-version-information-part-23.html)
[Part 3](http://sandcastleassist.blogspot.com/2012/02/sandcastle-version-information-part-33.html)

Comment: Thank you. But unfortunately, it seems like it will take ages for me to integrate his advises into SHFB process. For now it looks like I better spend fraction of that time and prepare a simple solution that just post-processes (decompresses, appends and recompresses) the CHM built with SHFB.